# jQuery set href attribute Dynamically

Tags: jquery, attributes, set

I am making an E-commerce site.

When the products list loads from the database the links to add them to the Shopping Cart look like this (Per product):

```
<a class="addtocart" data-id="<Product ID from the DB>">Add To Cart!</a>
```

Now, later, with jQuery I am adding more classes so it shows the content in a Fancybox window.

```
//Links with the class Fancybox upens in a nice modal window
$(".addtocart").addClass("fancybox"); //This Works

//Then, the window should show this page: addtocart.php, but not before sending a GET parameter so it knows Which product it is adding to the shopping cart
var href = "addtocart.php";
$(".addtocart").attr("href", href + "?id=" + $(this).attr("data-id"));
```

The last line of code is not working... it shows a link like this in the end:

```
<a data-id="10" class="addtocart fancybox" href="addtocart.php?id=undefined">Add to Cart!</a>
```

But should show the HREF part like this:

```
href="addtocart.php?id=10"
```

I've tried alot and it does not work. Thank you beforehand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(".addtocart").each(function () {
    $(this).attr("href", "addtocart.php?id=" + $(this).attr("data-id"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".addtocart").prop("href", function() {
    return "addtocart.php?id=" + $(this).data("id");
});
```